# citing inside underline/strike out :tex

Tags: citing, natbib, ulem

I am working on an article, where I need to strike out or underline some of the sentences with citations. I try to do this as `\uline{sentence1 \citep{reference1}, sentence continued \citep{reference2,reference3}}.`
but it shows this warning `extra }, or forgotten \end group`. 
I tried

1. To add `\protect` in front of each `\citep` or `\citet` which
   doesn't work.
2. To add the citations as `\mbox{\citex{reference1}}`, which worked and warnings disappeared, but with `\mbox` the page breaks are also
   disappearing.

So, are there any solutions how to strike out/underline keeping the citations intact inside? 
PS:I'm using `ulem` and `natbib`.

Comment: Wondering if there is any recent/more elegant solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

This solution involves closing off your `\uline` and `\sout` invocations as you approach an invocation of `\citep`.  For those references, use `\ulineref` and `\soutref` as defined in this MWE.  Then, pick up the `\uline` and `\sout` where you left off, after the reference.  The reference itself will not break across a line, though of course the `\uline` and `\sout` will.

The solution here adapts the `censor` package to do both underlining and strikeout.  The depths of the lines can be changed with the `\censorruledepth`, as used in the `\ulineref` and `\soutref` macros.  I tried to match those value to the existing line depths of the `ulem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{censor}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\censorruleheight=.1ex %THICKNESS OF CENSOR RULE
\newlength\nextcharwidth
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@cenword[1]{%
  \setlength{\nextcharwidth}{\widthof{#1}}%
  \censorrule{\nextcharwidth}%
  \kern -\nextcharwidth%
  #1}
\makeatother
\newcommand\ulineref[1]{\censorruledepth=-.67ex\censor{#1}}
\newcommand\soutref[1]{\censorruledepth=.55ex\censor{#1}}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {MCOSW,
author = "Hugh Glaser and Afraz Jafri and Ian Millard",
title = "Managing co-reference on the semantic web",
journal = "WWW2009 Workshop: Linked Data on the Web (LDOW2009)",
month = "April",
year = "2009",
%
@article {MCOSX,
author = "Hugh Glaser and Afraz Jafri and Ian Millard",
title = "Managing co-reference on the semantic web",
journal = "WWW2009 Workshop: Linked Data on the Web (LDOW2009)",
month = "April",
year = "2009",
%
@article {MCOSY,
author = "Hugh Glaser and Afraz Jafri and Ian Millard",
title = "Managing co-reference on the semantic web",
journal = "WWW2009 Workshop: Linked Data on the Web (LDOW2009)",
month = "April",
year = "2009",
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
I will begin the underline 
\uline{sentence1 }%
\ulineref{\citep{MCOSW}}%
\uline{, sentence continued onto next line. }%
\ulineref{\citep{MCOSX,MCOSY}}%
\uline{ blah blah} 
followed by normal text

I will begin the strikeout
\sout{sentence1 }%
\soutref{\citep{MCOSW}}%
\sout{, sentence continued onto next line. }%
\soutref{\citep{MCOSX,MCOSY}}%
\sout{ blah blah} 
followed by normal text

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]